# Using a visual tool to view changes on git repository

Tags: git, difftool

I'm coming to an existing project in which people used git to track everything from scratch. I want to have a tool to view the differences between several commits. gitk does a good job, but talking about human readability, it's does not facilitate me much.
Is there a better solution? I'm looking for a set of tools that allow me to easily compare branches (some how like winmerge - Display two version in parallel and highlight the changes), and running on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find NbGit (a git plugin for Netbeans) make this job very easy.

Answer (score 1):

[Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) supports Mac. You can configure Git to use it as the diff tool.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please suggest an easy way that I can compare two branches (not just two files) with this tool + git?